# In x86, why do I have the same instruction two times, with reversed operands?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, assembly, x86-64

I am doing several experiments with `x86` asm trying to see how common language constructs map into assembly. In my current experiment, I am trying to see specifically how C language pointers map to register-indirect addressing. I have written a fairly hello-world like pointer program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main (void)
{
    int value    = 5;
    int *int_val = &value;

    printf ("The value we have is %d\n", *int_val);
    return 0;
}
```

and compiled it to the following asm using: `gcc -o pointer.s -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables pointer.c`:[1][2]

```
        .file   "pointer.c"
        .section        .rodata
.LC0:
        .string "The value we have is %d\n"
        .text
        .globl  main
        .type   main, @function
main:
;------- function prologue
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
;---------------------------------
        subq    $32, %rsp
        movq    %fs:40, %rax
        movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
        xorl    %eax, %eax
;----------------------------------
        movl    $5, -20(%rbp)   ; This is where the value 5 is stored in `value` (automatic allocation)
;----------------------------------
        leaq    -20(%rbp), %rax ;; (GUESS) If I have understood correctly, this is where the address of `value` is 
                                ;; extracted, and stored into %rax
;----------------------------------
        movq    %rax, -16(%rbp) ;; 
        movq    -16(%rbp), %rax ;; Why do I have two times the same instructions, with reversed operands???
;----------------------------------
        movl    (%rax), %eax
        movl    %eax, %esi
        movl    $.LC0, %edi
        movl    $0, %eax
        call    printf
;----------------------------------
        movl    $0, %eax
        movq    -8(%rbp), %rdx
        xorq    %fs:40, %rdx
        je      .L3
        call    __stack_chk_fail
.L3:
        leave
        ret
        .size   main, .-main
        .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.9.1-16ubuntu6) 4.9.1"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

**My issue is that I don't understand why it contains the instruction `movq` two times, with reversed operands.** Could someone explain it to me?

[1]: I want to avoid having my asm code interspersed with cfi directives when I don't need them at all.

[2]: My environment is `Ubuntu 14.10`, `gcc 4.9.1` (modified by ubuntu), and `Gnu assembler (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.24.90.20141014`, configured to target `x86_64-linux-gnu`

Comment: If you don't tell gcc to optimize, it will produce *extremely* stupid code. As you've seen, it stores all local variables on the stack, even if it could easily be kept in a register. To get sensible code, tell gcc to optimize with `-O3`.

Comment: I can only echo EOF's comment. I find that `-O` is the most readable for me: `-O3` can apply transforms that impede traceability of source code in the assembly. For the same reason you used `-fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables`, you may also like `-fomit-frame-pointer` (for simple functions, the resulting assembly is in fact lighter and easier to follow). Don't read code generated with `-O0` unless you have time to waste.

Comment: @EOF yeah, I've seen what it does with `-O3`, and while it's cleaner, it has optimized out my pointers (and far more), and this way I get to lose what I wanted to see originaly: How pointers map to register indirect addressing.

Comment: if you want variables to not be optimized out, you can also use `-Og`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe it will be clearer if you reorganize your blocks:

```
;----------------------------------
    leaq    -20(%rbp), %rax     ; &value
    movq    %rax, -16(%rbp)     ; int_val
;----------------------------------
    movq    -16(%rbp), %rax     ; int_val
    movl    (%rax), %eax        ; *int_val
    movl    %eax, %esi          ; printf-argument
    movl    $.LC0, %edi         ; printf-argument (format-string)
    movl    $0, %eax            ; no floating-point numbers
    call    printf
;----------------------------------
```

The first block performs `int *int_val = &value;`, the second block performs `printf ...`. Without optimization, the blocks are independent.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're not doing any optimization, gcc creates very simple-minded code that does each statement in the program one at a time without looking at any other statement.  So in your example, it stores a value into the variable `int_val`, and then the very next instruction reads that variable again as part of the next statement.  In both cases, it is using `%rax` as the temporary to hold value, as that's the first register generally used for things.